# Using the DatabaseServerLoginModule in JBoss 7

Tags: jboss7.x

How do I have to configure a JBoss 7.1.1 server to use the DatabaseServerLoginModule when authenticating remote clients of my application?

Comment: I'm looking at this site: http://docs.jboss.org/jbosssecurity/docs/6.0/security_guide/html/Login_Modules.html#sect-DatabaseServerLoginModule right now and what i'm confused about is what is the difference between the Role column and the RoleGroup Column...

Answer (score 0):

create a table with 3 columns:

```
rolename, username and password. (or with name you need)
```

in your server xml declare your datasource, next put:

```
            <security-domain name="mydomain">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/MyDS"/>
                        <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from tab_credential where username=?"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select rolename, 'Roles' from tab_credential where username=?"/>
                        <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
```